# How to choose the right scheduler for unit-tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, junit4, rx-java

I have the following code to test:

```
public class MyInteractor implements Interactor<String, Boolean> {

  private MyRepository repository;

  @Inject
  public MyInteractor(MyRepository repository) {
      this.repository = repository;
  }

  @Override
  public Observable<Boolean> createObservable(final String s) {
      return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Boolean>() {
          @Override
          public void call(Subscriber<? super Boolean> subscriber) {

              Boolean response = repository.call(s);

              subscriber.onNext(response);
              subscriber.onCompleted();
          }
      })
              .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
   }
}
```

I wrote the following unit test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyInteractorTest {

  @Mock
  MyRepository repository;

  @InjectMocks
  MyInteractor interactor;

  @Before
  public void init() {
      when(repository.call(any(String.class)))
              .thenReturn(true);
  }

  @Test
  public void myTest() throws Exception {

      Observable<Boolean> interactorObservable =
              interactor.createObservable("hello");
      TestSubscriber<Boolean> subscriber = TestSubscriber.create();

      interactorObservable.subscribe(subscriber);

      subscriber.assertNoErrors();

      subscriber.assertCompleted();
      subscriber.assertReceivedOnNext(singletonList(true));
  }
}
```

When I run the unit test it fails on `subscriber.assertCompleted()`. However if I remove `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` in `MyInteractor.createObservable()` everything works fine.

Is there a way to make the test run to completion and not to remove the line `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was because `myTest` wasn't aware of there's stuff running on another thread, so it continues to run assertions before Observable returns.

Use [`RxJavaHooks`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/plugins/RxJavaHooks.html) to instrument IO Scheduler returning Immediate Scheduler in unit tests.

For example: `RxJavaHooks.setOnIOScheduler(scheduler -> Schedulers.immediate())`